# Amazon AWS - Fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such device or address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-web-services

I am trying to deploy rails 3 application on using AWS instance. For deployment, I am using opsworks services and also accessing private github repository for deployment. When start the instance, getting following errors.

```
[2015-03-10T04:34:32+00:00] INFO: Running queued delayed notifications before re-raising exception
[2015-03-10T04:34:32+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
[2015-03-10T04:34:32+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
[2015-03-10T04:34:32+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/lib/aws/opsworks/cache.stage1/chef-stacktrace.out
[2015-03-10T04:34:32+00:00] ERROR: git[Download Custom Cookbooks] (opsworks_custom_cookbooks::checkout line 29) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '128'
---- Begin output of git ls-remote "https://github.com/user_name/repository.git" HEAD ----
STDOUT:
STDERR: fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such device or address
---- End output of git ls-remote "https://github.com/user_name/repository.git" HEAD ----
Ran git ls-remote "https://github.com/user_name/repository.git" HEAD returned 128
[2015-03-10T04:34:32+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

Please help.

Answer (score 15):

The solution for me was to edit App Repository URL in the OpsWorks stack. Change it from:

**https://github.com/user_name/repository.git**

to

**git@github.com:user_name/repository.git**